# Finding lower bound based on solved recurrence relation

Tags: asymptotics, recurrence-relations, upper-lower-bounds

I have a recurrence tree for the relation of
$$T(n)=T(\sqrt{n}) + T(n-\sqrt{n}) + O(n),$$

which solves to $O(n+n\sqrt{n})$. I'm trying to use what I have from this to provide a lower bound on the running time.

What's the best way to tackle this?